# How to break down the time consumption when using Google Bigquery data streaming?

Tags: stream, google-bigquery

I'm streaming data from local files into Google Bigquery. My code:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
TableDataInsertAllRequest request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rowList);
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = mBigquery.tabledata().insertAll(ConfigConstants.PROJECT_ID, mDataset, tableId, request).execute();
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)/1000 + "s for one request with list size " + rowList.size());
```

rowList.size()=10000 and I ran exactly the same code to stream the same data set into the same bigquery dataset on four machines. As I can see in the output of my code, three of the machines took 20ish seconds to finish one request, while the other one only took 5ish seconds.
What are the possible reasons for such a big difference in stream speed?

A detail is that, at the beginning I thought it could be due to different network connections, so I just plug out the cable from the 5ish-seconds machine and plug it into one of the other three 20ish-seconds machine, but the speed just stayed on 20ish....

Why's that...